# Associating and Linked User Accounts in WSO2 IS 5.10

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We want to merge two accounts in IdP. For example, if there are two accounts on Apps xyz as IdP (Account 1 = zan, Account 2 = liy), can the customer log in to Account 1 and merge with Account 2? How can we identify that both accounts are actually the same customer?
any advice? thank you

Answer (score 1):

> We want to merge two accounts in IdP

By IdP do you mean the WSO2 Identity Server or a federated Idp configured in the WSO2 Identity Server.

If you want to merge two accounts inside the WSO2 Identity Server, a user can do it via the user-portal like this https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/user-portal/#linked-accounts

If you want to give that functionality through your application you can use this REST API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/association-rest-api/#/me/post_me_associations Which is also the one used in the above-mentioned user-portal for account linking.

But if you are looking to associate accounts from a federated IDP configured in the WSO2 Identity Server then this answer should do https://stackoverflow.com/a/61907398/4256000

Answer (score 0):

You can link a user account in a third party application. To read more about how to do that please refer [this blog](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/social-account-linking-with-wso2-identity-server-78b8a566e225).

Currently, in the user portal, we don't validate if the linked accounts belong to the same user.

Also if you need further clarifications regarding the WSO2 identity server or its features, please feel free to join our [slack channel](https://app.slack.com/client/TDW0W5E92) and we'll be happy to assist you with any question you have regarding the product.